# Not Response get access token oauth 2.0 API UBER in ASP NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uber-api

I'm using this method, I recover the error "The interruption of an existing connection has been forced by the remote host"

```
public static async void GetAccessToken()
    {
      var client = new HttpClient();

      // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
      var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new[] {
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret","xxxxx"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id","xxxxx"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","authorization_code"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri","http://localhost"),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code","xxxxx")
        });

      // Get the response.
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
          "https://domain-uber.com/oauth/v2/token",
          requestContent);

      // Get the response content.
      HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

      // Get the stream of the content.
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
      {
        var result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: SOLUTIONS HERE!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655566/c-sharp-rest-api-call-working-in-postman-not-in-code

Comment: Thank's @DanWilson, my problem was the version in protocol default in framework installed.